# Расположение элементов в XML разметке

Tags: android, xml, view

Имеется вот такой макет:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть 3 `TextView`:

- "Мой счет"
- "*1801"
- "Установлен"

Мне нужно чтоб "*1801" и "Установлен" всегда были отображены в полной размере, а вот если мы имеем длинный "Мой счет" и он не влезает в экран то применялся `elipsize`. При этом очень важно, чтоб "Мой счет" и "*1801" были прям рядом, как будто это один `TextView`.

Вопрос в том, что я не могу сообразить как правильно задать разметку элементов. Если кто подскажет, буду признателен.

Comment: очень важно, чтоб "Мой счет" и "*1801" были прям рядом, как будто это один TextView  –  а почему бы не сделать реально один? По разметке - показывай, что уже накодил

Comment: Потому что *1801 должно быть видно всегда, а если это будет 1 TextView, то сперва скроется номер счёта, а потом название.

Comment: ну почему же? делай gravity left и всё

Comment: Если текст будет очень длинный то номер счёта не влезет. А мне надо чтоб номер счёта был виден всегда, а название если оно не влезает скрывалось ellipsize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А если так (без спейсингов, падингов и мэржингов):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="VISA"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0sp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Мой счет" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0sp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:text="*1801"
    />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Установлен">
        Установлен
    </Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Нет, так получается что текст с номером счета занимает почти все пространство, а текст с названием в начале имеет минимальный размер. А тут суть в том, чтоб текст с названием счета занимал максимально возможное место, но при этом чтоб не урезались вьюхи остальные. И при этом если название короткое, то он занимал ровно столько места сколько нужно чтоб влез текст

Answer (score 1):

Пришлось написать вот такую View:

```
 class SeparateRestrictTextView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : ViewGroup(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    private var inited: Boolean = false
    private var showSeparatedRestrictionMode: Boolean = false

    @get:Px
    private val fadeOffset: Int by lazyUnsafe { context.dpToPx(FADE_OFFSET) }

    init {
        inflate(context, R.layout.view_separate_restrict_text, this)
        context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.SeparateRestrictTextView).apply {
            if (hasValue(R.styleable.SeparateRestrictTextView_srtv_textAppearance)) {
                fadedText.setTextAppearance(getResourceId(R.styleable.SeparateRestrictTextView_srtv_textAppearance, View.NO_ID))
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    restrictionText.setTextAppearance(getResourceId(R.styleable.SeparateRestrictTextView_srtv_textAppearance, View.NO_ID))
                } else {
                    restrictionText.setTextAppearance(context, getResourceId(R.styleable.SeparateRestrictTextView_srtv_textAppearance, View.NO_ID))
                }
            }
            recycle()
        }
        inited = true
    }

    override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
        measureChildWithPadding(restrictionText, widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)
        measureChildWithPadding(fadedText, widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)

        val desiredWidth = if (fadedText.inEllipsizedMode) {
            showSeparatedRestrictionMode = true
            measureChildWithPadding(fadedText, widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec, fadeOffset + restrictionText.measuredWidth)
            fadedText.measuredWidth + fadeOffset + restrictionText.measuredWidth
        } else {
            showSeparatedRestrictionMode = false
            fadedText.measuredWidth
        }

        val desiredHeight = max(fadedText.measuredHeight, restrictionText.measuredHeight)

        setMeasuredDimension(
            measureDimension(desiredWidth, widthMeasureSpec),
            measureDimension(desiredHeight, heightMeasureSpec)
        )
    }

    override fun onLayout(changed: Boolean, left: Int, top: Int, right: Int, bottom: Int) {
        if (showSeparatedRestrictionMode) {
            val restrictionTop = (bottom - top - restrictionText.measuredHeight) / 2
            restrictionText.layout(
                right - left - restrictionText.measuredWidth,
                restrictionTop,
                right - left,
                restrictionTop + restrictionText.measuredHeight
            )
        } else {
            restrictionText.layout(0, 0, 0, 0)
        }

        val fadedTextTop = (bottom - top - fadedText.measuredHeight) / 2
        val fadedTextRightRight = if (showSeparatedRestrictionMode) {
            right - left - restrictionText.measuredWidth - fadeOffset
        } else {
            right - left
        }
        fadedText.layout(
            0,
            fadedTextTop,
            fadedTextRightRight,
            fadedTextTop + fadedText.measuredHeight
        )
    }

    fun setContent(faded: String?, restriction: String?, separator: String) {
        if (faded.isNullOrEmpty() && restriction.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            isGone = true
            return
        }
        isVisible = true
        fadedText.text = listOfNotNull(faded?.takeIf { it.isNotEmpty() }, restriction).joinToString(separator)
        restrictionText.text = restriction
    }

    override fun addView(child: View?) {
        if (!inited) {
            super.addView(child)
        }
    }

    private fun measureDimension(desiredSize: Int, measureSpec: Int): Int {
        val specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpec)
        val specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpec)

        return when (specMode) {
            MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED -> desiredSize
            MeasureSpec.AT_MOST -> min(desiredSize, specSize)
            else -> specSize
        }
    }

    private fun measureChildWithPadding(child: View, parentWidthMeasureSpec: Int, parentHeightMeasureSpec: Int, rightPadding: Int = 0) {
        val lp = child.layoutParams

        val childWidthMeasureSpec = getChildMeasureSpec(parentWidthMeasureSpec, rightPadding, lp.width)
        val childHeightMeasureSpec = getChildMeasureSpec(parentHeightMeasureSpec, 0, lp.height)

        child.measure(childWidthMeasureSpec, childHeightMeasureSpec)
    }

    private companion object {
        @Dp
        const val FADE_OFFSET = 6f
    }
}
```

XML разметка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fadedText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/restrictionText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:maxLines="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</merge>
```

А это в attrs:

```
<declare-styleable name="SeparateRestrictTextView">
    <attr name="srtv_textAppearance" format="reference" />
</declare-styleable>
```

Comment: мне кажется `attrs` где-то потерялось :)

Comment: Усп=)) спасиб ща добавлю